# Dudas sobre arrays de punteros

Tags: c++, array

Tengo una duda entre el comportamiento de dos declaraciones de arrays. Y no esta relacionada con la asignación dinámica de memoria, sino como acceder a los objetos del array. Me explico.

#### Caso a:

Supongamos que defino un array de la siguiente forma.

```
 Time t1(12,13,15);//los parametros del constructor son hora, minuto y segundo.
 Time t2(17,15,18);
 Time *pTArr[2]; //no se hace llamada al constructor.
 pTArr[0]=&t1;
 pTArr[1]=&t2;
 pTArr[1]->print();//imprime hora:minuto:segundo.
```

En este caso pTArr[i], es un puntero donde:

- `pTArr[i]` es la dirección donde está el objeto i que apunta, y
- `*pTArr[i]`, es el objeto al que apunta.

Funcionamiento típico de un puntero.

#### Caso b:

```
  Time *pTArr=new Time[2]; // Se inicializa y se llama al construtor Time();

  pTArr[0].print(); //cuando antes era  pTArr[1]->print().
```

Por lo que veo, en este caso sería algo así:

- `pTArr[i]` es el objeto al que apunta.
- `&pTArr[i]` es la dirección donde está el objeto `i` que apunta.

¿Por qué se comportan de forma diferente, no son ambos un array de punteros a objetos `Time`? En el caso a, es el típico comportamiento de punteros. Pero el caso b, no se comportan como puntero (`puntero=dirección`, `*puntero=objeto`).

Cualquier aclaración, preguntad. Saludos, Julio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas mezclando, de manera peligrosa, diferentes conceptos.

- **Caso a**: La declaración `Time *pTArr[2]` está creando una formación<sup>1</sup> de dos elementos cuyo tipo es "Puntero a `Time`".
- **Caso b**: La declaración `Time *pTArr=new Time[2]` está creando un "Puntero a `Time`" apuntando a un espacio en memoria dinámica que contiene dos objetos `Time`.

> ¿Por qué se comportan de forma diferente, no son ambos un array de punteros a objetos `Time`?

La diferencia es sutil y comprendo que puede resultar confusa, pero en el primer caso la formación de dos elementos contiene "Punteros a `Time`", en el segundo caso no tienes una formación si no un puntero apuntando a dos objetos `Time` contiguos.

Dado que no es cierto que ambos sean formaciones de punteros a objetos `Time`, es normal que se comporten de manera diferente. Si quieres que el *caso a* se comporte como el *caso b*, tu código debería ser:

`Caso a`

```
Time t1(12, 13, 15); // Los parámetros del constructor son hora, minuto y segundo.
Time t2(17, 15, 18);
Time pTArr[2]; // Se llama al constructor por defecto Time().
//  ~ <--- Sin especificar "puntero a Time".
pTArr[0] = t1;
//        ~ <--- Sin pedir la dirección de 't1', se llama al operador de copia.
pTArr[1] = t2;
//        ~ <--- Sin pedir la dirección de 't2', se llama al operador de copia.
pTArr[1].print(); // Imprime hora:minuto:segundo.
//      ~ <--- Punto, no flecha.
```

`Caso b`

```
Time *pTArr=new Time[2];
pTArr[0].print();
```

Si quieres que el *caso b* se comporte como el *caso a*, tu código debería ser:

`Caso a`

```
Time t1(12,13,15); // Los parámetros del constructor son hora, minuto y segundo.
Time t2(17,15,18);
Time *pTArr[2]; // No se hace llamada al constructor.
pTArr[0] = &t1;
pTArr[1] = &t2;
pTArr[1]->print(); // Imprime hora:minuto:segundo.
```

`Caso b`

```
Time **pTArr=new Time*[2];
//   ^^              ~ <--- formación de punteros
//   || <--- doble puntero
pTArr[0]->print(); // Esto fallará porque no hay nada en pTArr[0].
```

---

1. También conocida como arreglo o en inglés array.

Comment: En el caso b. Entonces seria como un arreglo de dos objetos TIme referenciado por un puntero ?. Puedo ver en algún lado como se trabaja con este ejemploTime **pTArr=new Time*[2];

Comment: ¿En qué "caso b"? ¿en el tuyo o en alguno de los que he modificado en mi respuesta?

Comment: En este caso:Caso b: La declaración Time *pTArr=new Time[2] está creando un "Puntero a Time" apuntando a un espacio en memoria dinámica que contiene dos objetos Time. Es un espacio dinámico de memoria donde hay array de dos objetos time referenciados por un puntero.

Comment: Efectivamente, en ese caso, el puntero `pTArr` apunta a un espacio de memoria en que hay almacenados contiguamente dos objetos de tipo `Time`, esa memoria se ha pedido en tiempo de ejecución mediante `new`.

Comment: Y la última cuestión TIme **pTarr=new TIme *[2], sería lo mismo que TIme *pTarr=new Time[2]{Time(),Time()}. Es una definición que vi usando llaves. De verdad muchas gracias me está quedandk muy claro.

Comment: No, no es ni por asomo lo mismo. `Time **pTarr=new Time *[2];` crea un arreglo en tiempo de ejecución de punteros a `Time` que se guarda en un puntero a puntero a `Time`. `Time *pTarr=new Time[2]{Time(),Time()};` crea un arreglo en tiempo de ejecución de objetos `Time` que se guarda en un puntero a `Time`, el código entre llaves (`{}`) es la inicialización de los elementos del arreglo creado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76792/discussion-between-jcpardo-and-paula-plus-plus).

Comment: muchas gracias todo claro, voy abrir una pregunta respecto a un puntero a un array de punteros a objetos Time. para no alargar mas este caso. Gracias.